# Do hinge screws become more tight-fitting over time once installed?

Tags: doors, woodworking, screws, hinges

I've noted newly installed hinge screws can be replaced more easily if replacement is within days after fitting. If left for weeks or more, they become considerably harder to remove due to friction.

Is this a normal process following installation of hinges? What could the mechanism be?

**Edit**: Weather could definitely be a factor, as pointed out in comments, but the changes took place within roughly the same environmental conditions. My mistake for not pointing this out earlier.

Comment: The wood swells / shrinks due to seasonal / weather changes...

Comment: And notice that (counter intuitively), the screws will be tighter when the wood *shrinks*, and looser when it swells.

Comment: @Martin - why do you think that's counter-intuitive?  It seems obvious that when the wood gets smaller, the hole in it gets smaller.

Comment: @TobySpeight Because I had a raging argument with my woodwork teacher about this about 45 years ago.  You are correct, but he took the opposite view.

Comment: On top of shrinkage many screws even stainless oxidize somewhat and the oxide layer also makes it tougher to remove the screw, this is real obvious with galvanized screws in the weather, but happens to a small extent indoors with shrinkage being the major cause.

Comment: What kind of hinge--door?   cabinet door?   And what material is the frame into which they are screwed?

Comment: Pine jamb (I think). Interior door. A2 stainless steel screws. Stainless steel ball-bearing hinges.

Comment: Old trick of the trade: keep a bar of unscented soap (like Ivory) with you when mounting things with wood screws and rub the screw threads over the soap before using them. It makes them come back out with less stress even years later.